# Ошибка при вставке в таблицу Incorrect string value: '\xF0

Tags: php, mysqli

ни как не могу решить проблему.

В переменну `$text` залетает текст с формы

```
$text = trim(htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["text"]),ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

Сама страница с которой идет отправка и на которой обрабатывается содержит `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Вот как подключаюсь к базе

```
$db = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) 
or die("Ошибка соеденения с базой данных:" . mysqli_error($db));
$query_coding = "SET NAMES 'utf8'";
mysqli_query($db,$query_coding);
```

Поле таблицы куда вставляю текст в кодировке `utf8_general_ci` да и сама таблица в той же кодировке.

Перед вставкой проверил таким способом `echo mb_detect_encoding($text);` в ответ получил `UTF-8`

Помогите разобратся, почему не вставляет в тексте содержатся вот такие символы  без них все работает а с ними нет :(

Comment: Используйте `uft8_unicode_ci`

Comment: @KostaB. Пробовал в таблице uft8_unicode_ci и windows 1251 не работает

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем дело было вот в чем. В тексте встречаются символы, которые состоят не из 3 байтов как в UTF-8, а из 4-х ( как раз мои символы  ) .

Для того чтобы все заработало в соеденение базы изменил:

`$query_coding = "SET NAMES 'utf8'";` на `$query_coding = "SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'";`

То есть с UTF 8 на UTF8MB4 ну и в самой таблице, для поля в котором хранится текст изменил кодировку с `utf8_general_ci` на `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` вот и все решение проблемы.